# What Licenses am I allowed to use when selling Ubuntu wallpapers?

Tags: desktop-background, deb, proprietary, canonical, license

I am making Debian packages containing wallpapers that I want to sell through Canonical (https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/). Canonical does not (that I have found) list allowed licenses for wallpapers that are to be sold through Canonical. What licenses are permitted for wallpapers to be sold?

Comment: By extension, what licenses are allowed for any paid or free, or open source software through the App Developer portal? The documentation is beyond pathetic in that even after ten minutes hunting, [the document it refers to does not exist](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntudeveloperportal/+bug/887208).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already point out in my comment, the documentation isn't currently going to help you.

I would go in with the assumption that you can license a wallpaper under the same terms as most software (in that you can hold copyright, or a license to redistribute it and you can give people a license for it - this is all true in most civilised parts of the world) but you should confirm ***directly with Canonical*** that they'll accept a paid wallpaper package before you do anything.

That you're asking the question suggests that you might be thinking of a non-traditional license. Perhaps if you can expand on that, you might get a better answer... But if you're thinking of a "standard" commercial software license, *I think* you'll be fine.